# Integral Quantity Interpretation

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors, integration

Is there any natural interpretation for the following quantity?
$$\int_{\vec{r}(t)} \nabla(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A})dt \ .$$
Where: $$\vec{v} = \frac{d \vec{r}(t)}{dt} \ ,$$ is the velocity of the path over which the integration is done; and $\vec{A}$ is some vector field (with units of momentum). I believe it can be rewritten:
$$\int_{\vec{r}(t)} \nabla(d \vec{r} \cdot \vec{A}) \ ,$$
we could also rewrite:
$$\int_{\vec{r}(t)} \nabla(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A})dt = \int_{\vec{r}(t)} \left[( \vec{v} \cdot \nabla)\vec{A} + \vec{v} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A}) \right] dt$$

Now if $\partial A /\partial t =0$, then the first term is equal to the total derivative, so it can be written:

$$\int_{\vec{r}(t)} \nabla(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{A})dt =  \Delta (\vec{A}) + \int_{\vec{r}(t)}\vec{v} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A}) dt$$

It would be nicer to see if there was something better though.

Comment: Did you find this object somewhere? If so it would help people if you gave more context on where it came from.

Comment: The Lorentz force law, written in terms of the magnetic vector potential $B= \nabla \times A$.

Comment: I see, but you can just put that information into clarifying that in the question instead of the comments, you can edit how you arrived at this starting from the lorentz force law to your expression. You mention later you can rewrite it, shouldn't the logic be in the other direction? That you took the triple product and rewrote it using scalar products and are now asking what those terms mean?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the standard expansion of the vector identity, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities) $$\nabla (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b) =  (\mathbf a \cdot \nabla)\mathbf b + \mathbf a \times (\nabla \times \mathbf  b) + (\mathbf b \cdot \nabla)\mathbf a + \mathbf b \times (\nabla \times \mathbf  a) \tag{1}$$
to $\mathbf a= \mathbf v$ and $\mathbf b= \mathbf A$ and note that while the $\mathbf v$ is a function of time it is independent of position, hence $\nabla \times \mathbf v =0 $ and $(\mathbf A \cdot \nabla)\mathbf v =0$. Therefore,
$$\nabla (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A) =  (\mathbf v \cdot \nabla)\mathbf A + \mathbf v \times (\nabla \times \mathbf  A) \tag{2}.$$
Next, replace the E and B fields in Newton's equation with their potentials
$$\frac{d}{dt} (m\mathbf v)=q(\mathbf E + \mathbf {v\times B}) \\= -q\left(\nabla \phi  + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf A + \mathbf v \times (\nabla \times \mathbf A) \right)\tag{3}$$
Using eq (2) the 3rd term on the right can be written as:
$$\frac{d(m\mathbf v)}{d t} + q\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbf A+  (\mathbf v \cdot \nabla)\mathbf A \right)  =-q\left(\nabla \phi  +\nabla (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A) \right)$$

On the left side in the parentheses we find the convective time derivative of $\mathbf A$, that is

$$\frac{d\mathbf A}{dt}= \frac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial t} + (\mathbf v \cdot \nabla) \mathbf A \tag{4},$$ therefore,

$$\frac{d(m\mathbf v)}{dt} + q\frac{d\mathbf A}{dt}  =-q\left(\nabla \phi  +\nabla (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A) \right)$$ which gives us
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left(m\mathbf v + q\mathbf A \right)  =-q\left(\nabla \phi  +\nabla (\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A) \right) \tag{5}$$
or $$\frac{d}{dt} \left(m\mathbf v + q\mathbf A \right)  =-q\nabla \left(\phi  +\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A \right) \tag{5a}$$

Eq (5a) shows how the scalar potential $\phi$ is modified to $\phi + \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A $ in the presence of a moving charge in a magnetic field, while the total momentum including that of the charge and of the field is now $m\mathbf v + q\mathbf A$ whose time rate is the gradient of the total potential.

Now to the time integral in your question, according to eq. (5a)

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt \nabla(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A) = -\int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt \left[\frac{d}{dt} \left(m\mathbf v + q\mathbf A \right)  + q\nabla (\phi  \right]\\
=- \left[m\mathbf v + q\mathbf A \right]_{t_0}^{t_1} -q\int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt\nabla \phi $$ or using a $\Delta $ notation:

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt \nabla(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf A)
=- \Delta\left[m\mathbf v + q\mathbf A \right] -q\int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt\nabla \phi \tag{6}$$

Comment: Thank you. While my question was inspired by E&M, what I an primarily interested in is a “geometric” interpretation of the quantity when $A$ is a generic vector field.

Comment: In the comment above you mentioned the Lorentz force, specifically "*The Lorentz force law, written in terms of the magnetic vector potential B=∇×A*" being at the root of your question, hence my answer.

Comment: I did not say that in my original question because I was looking more for a geometric interpretation for an arbitrary vector field; however, I was pushed in the comments to explain what inspired me to ask this question. Perhaps I should ask in the math stackexchange instead